# Cublas error link 2019

Tags: cuda, gpu, cublas

I am trying to use the cublas toolkit provided by Nvidia. I tried a simple code so that I am sure it is working first

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
int main(){
   cublasHandle_t handle;
   cublasCreate_v2(&handle);
   cublasDestroy_v2(handle);
}
```

it gives me an error link

```
1>------ Build started: Project: trial_cuda_basic_las, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
1>  
1>  E:\GPU\Trials\trial_cuda_basic_las\trial_cuda_basic_las>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "E:\GPU\Trials\trial_cuda_basic_las\trial_cuda_basic_las\kernel.cu" 
1>  kernel.cu
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cublasCreate_v2@4 referenced in function _main
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cublasDestroy_v2@4 referenced in function _main
1>E:\GPU\Trials\trial_cuda_basic_las\Debug\trial_cuda_basic_las.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

N.B.: I linked cublas.lib in the project properties link

Comment: are you building a 32-bit project?  Build an x64 project.  There is [no support for 32-bit CUBLAS in CUDA 7.5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#x86-32-bit-support).

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can I do it ???

Comment: ok I tried what u have just said but it still gives me this error
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cublasCreate_v2 referenced in function main
    1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cublasDestroy_v2 referenced in function main

Comment: have you added cublas.lib to the 64-bit project properties?  If you study one of the cuda sample projects that use cublas, you should be able to determine the correct project setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked :D :D I forgot to re add it :D :D